# Слетела кодировка MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка

Привет!

На одном из сайтов вместо правильной кодировки одни вопросики. То ли база упала, то ли еще что, но никаких действий со стороны вебмастера не было. Проверил — аптайм базы 2 часа, так что, видимо, она падала и какая-то настройка слетела.

В phpmyadmin таблицы отображаются нормально, кодировка стоит у таблиц 1251, как надо.

Подскажите, куда смотреть? Желательно через phpmyadmin. :)

з.ы. Такая проблема толко с данными из базы, так что проблема явно в ней.

Спасибо!

Comment: В неправильной кодировке отображаются страницы сайта, собранные из базы данных?  Так посмотрите, установлена ли кодировка на страницах сайта. Meta charset

Comment: @Erick  Flatcher, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Находится первым запросом в яндексе.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'");
```

http://dev.ezoterik.info/mysql-i-russkaya-kodirovka/